What English words have a similar sound or meaning to the latin word "semper"?
What English words derive from the latin word semper?

A contributor to wiktionary.com writes that the word "semper" is the concatenation of two seperate words; sem and per.
The word "sḗm" means somthing like “one”.
sḗm is the root of the Latin semel.
The English word for sḗmel is “once”.
Cognates include Ancient Greek εἷς (heîs) and Sanskrit सकृत् (sa-kṛ́t).
The word semper is related to the words singulus and single.

I’m voting to close this question because this question isn't about learning English.  There's no way to learn English by taking a word in latin and then looking for words that derrive from it.   For what it's worth, there is a word Sempiternal  (=unchanging, everlasting, as an aspect of god)

also semperannual
sempergreen
semperjuvenescent
semperlenity sempervind   All exceedingly rare and

The Latin 'semper' means "always" or "forever". Oxford does list a number of words with the prefix, but all are marked either as "archaic", "literary" (meaning use is confined mainly to poetry and not used in everyday speech) or "rare". It appears there are no common English words that have "semper" directly in their etymology. But the component parts of that word are definitely in English words. Loads of them.
'Sem' means "one" or "whole", but it also implies something that can be divided. So we have the English prefix semi, which means part of, or half of something and is seen in words like semicircle, semicolon, semiannual etc.
'Per' means "thoroughly", "through", or "completely". This is a prefix in many English words such as perfect (completely made) which is directly from the Latin perfectus. Most English words with the per- prefix do come in whole from Latin, such as perfect (Latin, perfectus) or permanent (Latin permanentem).
